# Elm: Decode a JSON array with a single element into a string

Tags: json, frontend, elm, decoder

had a look for something like this, but can't find the exact issue.

I have a JSON back from server side validation that looks like:

```
{ 
  "field": ["field-name"], 
  "messages":["message","message"]
}
```

What I would like to do is decode it into an elm record like

```
{ field: String, messages: List String }
```

However, I'm having trouble with the err, field field. I'm having trouble turning a single element JSON array into just a string of that element.

Is it even possible with Decode, or am I better of Decoding it into a List and then just grabbing the head from the list.

This is what I have for the decode:

```
valErrorDecoder : Decode.Decoder ValError
valErrorDecoder =
decode ValError
    |> required "field" (Decode.list Decode.string)
    |> required "messages" (Decode.list Decode.string)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'v met the same issue. Tried both solutions. However, if empty list occurred in Json, "Maybe" is needed. Decode.index will not catch the fail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`Decode.index`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#index), that should do the trick.

```
valErrorDecoder : Decode.Decoder ValError
valErrorDecoder =
decode ValError
    |> required "field" (Decode.index 0 Decode.string)
    |> required "messages" (Decode.list Decode.string)
```

Comment: Thanks! A colleague suggested Decode.map, but this looks a bit simpler.

Answer (score 4):

You mention in a comment that a colleague suggested `Decode.map`. In case you're curious, here is what that (more complex) solution might look like:

```
firstElementDecoder : Decode.Decoder a -> Decode.Decoder a
firstElementDecoder baseDecoder = Decode.list baseDecoder
 |> Decode.map List.head
 |> Decode.andThen (Maybe.map Decode.succeed >> Maybe.withDefault (Decode.fail "Empty list"))
```

What's happening here? We begin by decoding a list of strings, then map the `List.head` function onto that list, giving a `Decoder (Maybe String)`. The function

```
Maybe.map Decode.succeed 
  >> Maybe.withDefault (Decode.fail "Empty list")
```

takes in a `Maybe` and turns it into a decoder, which either succeeds (with the value of the maybe) or fails (with an "Empty list" error message). We use this function as the argument to `Decode.andThen`, which:

1. Passes the `Maybe` from the list decoder into the function above, getting either a `Decode.succeed` or a `Decode.fail`
2. Runs the returned decoder, succeeding or failing with the appropriate value.

So, yes, `Decode.index 0` is easier! But it may be of interest to see the longer solution, too :-)

Comment: Thanks for adding this extra answer. It enabled me finally to build a Decoder Char that only succeeds if the input is a single character string. It also shows how arbitrary extra validation can be inserted into the Decoder chain.